# IndexOutOfBoundsException index 0 size 0 trying to edit an element in a populated arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, fragment, indexoutofboundsexception

I am trying to edit an element in an already populated arraylist but keep getting that error.
The method is called from a fragment but I can't seem to access the arraylist from the fragment or Anything the fragment is associated with. I can change the value I want anywhere else in the same class expect in that method which is called from the fragment. I will really appreciate the help thanks in advance.

Fragment Code

```
 MainActivity method = new MainActivity();

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    method.updateQuantity(Quantity);
    super.onDetach();
}
```

MainActivity code

```
public void updateQuantity(int Quantity){
    items.get(currentitem).setQuantity(Quantity);
}
```

Comment: What is `method`? and where do you set `currentitem`?

Comment: method is set to sue the main activity. ie.  MainActivity method = new MainActivity(); i set it dynamically i know this isn't the problem because i hard coded it to index 0 but still same issue arose.

Comment: Is 'items' empty?

Comment: no it is already populated I can update the list from any method that isn't in the fragment or somehow connected to it.

Answer (score 0):

If `items` is your ArrayList, then for `ArrayList.get`, it takes `integer(index)` as an argument and then returns the element of that index.

So, this `items.get(currentitem).setQuantity(Quantity)`) call is
very unsafe. Need to check the max index length first then try to access it.

```
public void updateQuantity(int Quantity){
    if(items != null and currentitem < items.size(){
       items.get(currentitem).setQuantity(Quantity);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have set currentitem to be either the position value provided by an onitemclicklistener or to the size -1 of the arraylist. i have manually changed which inex i want to access by hard coing index 0 which i know there is but still gave that error.

Comment: Your comment is not clear to me, can you explain it again

Comment: currentitem can only be an index that exist, either by geting an index from an onitemclicklistener or from the size of the arralist. i tried using index 0 in the place of currentItem to see if currentitem causes the issue but hadcoding a an existing index to edit still gives me the error.

Comment: Please add details error log and more code